# Oracle APEX takes a value from a function and uses it to open a new page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-5

I have a function that returns a value (e.g.27).
I am put this value to my page item (P2120_SYMPTOM_ID) and i want with this value to open with button another page (P2140).

I am going to button Link builder - target and i am using P2120_SYMPTOM_ID like this:

[image]

but unfortunatendly this value doesn't pass to my new page criteria.
How can i use this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just navigating to another page (as opposed to opening a modal window) then use action "Submit" on your button and create a branch to the new page. That is how navigation is supposed to be done. The link builder links are generated when the page is rendered and do not pick up session values.

Comment: Hi Koen Lostrie and thank you for your answer. 
When you use the "Submit", the page refreshes so it is not nice for the user. 
Maybe you're talking about something else that i don't get it. 
Can you please also give me an example with my pages (P2120 and P2140) and these three criteria? 
When should I use "Submit"? 
When i run my function or when i want to open my new page?

Comment: It's not clear from your question if the page the button links to is a modal page or normal page. If it is a normal page then a page submit - as I described - is the best solution. For a modal page you'll have a do some research, that is not as straightforward - explained [here](https://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2017/01/05/passing-data-in-and-out-of-apex-dialogs/)

Answer (score 1):

This is a common question, and relates to the fact the link uses values during page render, not what may have happened during interaction with the page

A common solution is presented in the Oracle forums here
https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/3725149/pass-client-side-state-to-modal-dialog

Alternatively, there is a free & supported FOEX Redirect plugin that also solves this problem
https://fos.world/ords/f?p=10000:1080

Comment: Hi Scott and thank you for your answer. I need your help with an example, because i can not understand how can i use my three parameters.
My current page is P2120 and my target page is P2140. Both pages have these three items: P2120_SESSION_ID and P2120_PATIENT_ID come from my database and work perfectly. 
The last parameter: P2120_SYMPTOM_ID comes from my function and i have the issiue. 
The same items exists in my target page starting with P2140... 
I wrote this: "f?p=&APP_ID.:2140:&APP_SESSION." but how can i use these criteria?

Comment: As for the alternative solution that you gave me with plug in, 
i can't find the exe plug in file, only examples, design and overview

Comment: The FOEX plugin is downloadable from github, there is a link on the page https://github.com/foex-open-source/fos-redirect

Comment: What do you mean by 'comes from function', can you further elaborate your example?

Comment: I have an item (P2120_SEARCH_SYMPTOM) with autocomplete text,  that user type the symptom and with my function i am searching my database (with some criteria) and returns the symptom_id of my table to my P2120_SYMPTOM_ID item.

Comment: I don't want to confuse you. Forget all the above and let's say I have two pages P2120 and P2140. The first one has P2120_SYMPTOM_ID item with default value 0 and the second page has P2140_SYMPTOM_ID item.
I open P2120 and after some calculations according to the user's choice on this page, the item P2120_SYMPTOM_ID gets the value 5.
   I want to open P2140 using P2120_SYMPTOM_ID (value 5) as criteria.
How can I do it?